# Logstash indices not reflecting in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

I have created the following **custom index** under output node in **logstash.conf**...its been more than 1 hour, still **blend_test** doesn't reflect in the kibana indices server (elk_server_ip:9200/_cat/indices)

```
elasticsearch {
hosts => "elk_server_ip:9200"
manage_template => false
index => "blend_test*" 
  }
```

Please suggest if am doing something wrong....FYI, I have also restarted filebeat and logstash as well

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/nomi/unity/media/*.log

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\|%{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
  }
  date {
    locale => "en"
    match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    timezone => "America/New_York"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elk_server_ip:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "blend_test*" 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you ingesting the data? Update your question with your full logstash config and your filebeat config.

Comment: @leandrojmp , updated the post with both config files...thanks

Comment: can you try using the output elasticsearch index name without wildcard: "blend_test"

Comment: @victor index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

is working but i wanted something custom to be identified easily which is why i am using wildcard

Comment: ok, u mean * is not required?

Comment: isn't * mandatory?

Comment: for sure, "*" isn't mandatory

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't use wildcards in "index" setting from output plugin for elasticsearch:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index

```
index    
    Value type is string
    Default value is "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

The index to write events to. This can be dynamic using the %{foo} syntax. The default value will partition your indices by day so you can more easily delete old data or only search specific date ranges. Indexes may not contain uppercase characters. For weekly indexes ISO 8601 format is recommended, eg. logstash-%{+xxxx.ww}. LS uses Joda to format the index pattern from event timestamp. Joda formats are defined here.
```

If you want something "custom" you can use some fields: %{foo} syntax